# Sencha touch cordova splash screen

Tags: cordova, extjs, touch, screen, splash-screen

I am using cordova for native packaging.
Questions regarding below config.xml

> 1. What is res/android/ and Where this path exist of i need to create ?
> 2. Can we give any xyz.png instead of instead of xhdpi.png , if yes then where to keep those *.png(splash screen icons)
> 3. oes all this override icon and startup image given in app.js (sencha generated default app.js)?
> 4. How to give app icon instead of using default cordova icon ?

```
<platform name="android">
    <icon src="res/android/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/android/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/android/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/android/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
</platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

Configuration of Cordova icons and splash screens for Sencha Touch apps is done in the same way as for any other Cordova app, the [documentation here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens) covers this in detail.

You don't say which version of Cordova you are using, what does:

```
cordova -v
```

output?  This may change how splash screens and icons are configured in your project - over time this has changed.  You can look at the version of the above documentation link for your version of Cordova and it will tell you how to do this.

Comment: I am using cordova version 4.1.2 . And I did sencha cordova init com.mycompany.MyApp MyApp. So It has created cordova directory .Now I want to set splash screen , so for that I followed the document which you have shared . I need clarification on that only . Please go through four points(1-4) which I asked ?

Comment: A complete configuration with examples for Cordova 4 is [provided in the official documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens), in summary you add appropriate elements to config.xml for your project and put the splash and icon images somewhere in your project's workspace, then refer to that location in your config.xml entries for each icon and splash screen image (the example given uses a folder "res" which lives in the same folder as config.xml).